# Issue adding SQL FullText Search to an existing SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do a full text search but am having issues implementing it.  I have an Object which can have multiple "Titles".  I have a stored procedure that takes a language and country and returns a normalized result with the best "Title" based on the localization.
What I want to be able to do is perform a full text search on the "Title" table that will search all rows but then only return the normalized, default title.

To get the normalized result I have something like

```
NORMALIZING STATEMENT

SELECT MainObject.*, Title.Name, Description.Name
FROM MainObject
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Title.Name
    FROM Title
    WHERE Title.MainObject_ID = MainObject.ID AND Title.Language = @language
    ORDER BY Title.[Default] DESC
)
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Description.Name
    FROM Description
    WHERE Description.MainObject_ID = MainObject.ID AND Description.Language = @language
    ORDER BY Description.[Default] DESC
)
```

Say an object has 3 titles, Alpha, Bravo and Charlie with Alpha being the default Title.
I want to be able to do a full text search for Bravo.  The object that Bravo is linked to is found but is normalized with the above statement.  I.E search for "Bravo" and "Alpha" is returned as Title.Name.

The only way I can think of doing this is to first perform the Search such as

```
FULL-TEXT STATEMENT

SELECT Title.MainObject_ID, MAX(KEY_TBL.RANK)
FROM Title
INNER JOIN
FREETEXTTABLE(Title,Name,'Some Search') AS KEY_TBL
ON Title.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
WHERE KEY_TBL.RANK >= 50
GROUP BY Title.MainObjectID, KEY_TBL.RANK
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

This returns a list of MainObjects.  I can then run these through the top statement.  Is there a way to combine the two in a more elegant manor to thus get better performance?

UPDATE:
I can perform a WHERE IN on the full text statement but I'm not sure how to get the RANK back out to the main statement so I can have final output ordered by descending RANK.

```
NORMALIZING STATEMENT
WHERE MainObject.ID IN
(
    FULL-TEXT STATEMENT
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there in the end....  I started with the full text search on the "title" Table, then joined this back to the MainObject Table and carried on from there.  I have to group by everything I want to select.

```
SELECT MainObject.ID, MAX(KEY_TBL.RANK) AS IndexRank, MainObject.OtherColumns, Title.Name, Description.Name
FROM Title AS FT_TBL
INNER JOIN
FREETEXTTABLE(Title,Name,'Some Search') AS KEY_TBL
ON FT_TBL.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
INNER JOIN
MainObject ON FT_TBL.MainObjectID = MainObject.ID
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Title.Name
    FROM Title
    WHERE Title.MainObject_ID = MainObject.ID AND Title.Language = @language
    ORDER BY Title.[Default] DESC
)
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Description.Name
    FROM Description
    WHERE Description.MainObject_ID = MainObject.ID AND Description.Language = @language
    ORDER BY Description.[Default] DESC
)
GROUP BY MainObject.ID, KEY_TBL.RANK, MainObject.OtherColumns, Title.Name, Description.Name
ORDER BY IndexRank desc
```